# INTERBASE bad parameter number error when using subqueries

Tags: delphi, syntax-error, c++builder, interbase

I have been working on switching over to an Interbase database from SQLITE.  One of the issues I have run into is a "bad parameter number" error.  So, I went back to one of the sample databases that Embarcadero supplies (EMPLOYEE) to tried various SQL commands to reproduce the problem.

So here is a scenario: I want a query that gives the average sales amount for all sales to a particular customer over a pre-specified amount.  So, here is a query that works for that:

```
SELECT AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) AS AvgSales
FROM SALES
WHERE TOTAL_VALUE > :TOTAL_VALUE
  AND CUST_NO = :CUSTNO
```

Now, I want to store that average in a table.  But how can you do that?  Here is what I tried:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <Column> = (SELECT AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) AS AvgSales
                FROM SALES
                WHERE TOTAL_VALUE > :TOTAL_VALUE
                  AND CUST_NO = :CUST_NO)
```

But when you try to execute that, it gives the error message "bad parameter number"

If you hard code the two parameters, it works fine:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <Column> = (SELECT AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) AS AvgSales
                FROM SALES
                WHERE TOTAL_VALUE > 10000
                  AND CUST_NO = 1001)
```

After more experimenting, it looks to me like any parameter in a subquery will generate that same error message rather than executing.  For example, this also generates the same error message (and hard coding the parameters works):

```
SELECT AMT
FROM
    (SELECT AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) AS AvgSales
     FROM  SALES
     WHERE TOTAL_VALUE > :TOTAL_VALUE
       AND CUST_NO = :CUSTNO
    ) X(Amt)
```

So, how do you go about storing such a value in an Interbase table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a procedure can solve your problem, the scheme :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATEAVERAGES(CUSTNO INTEGER,TOT NUMERIC())
AS 
DECLARE VARIABLE NEWVALUE NUMERIC();
BEGIN 
SELECT AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) FROM SALES WHERE TOTAL_VALUE>:TOT AND CUST_NO=:CUSTNO INTO :NEWVALUE;
UPDATE <table> SET <column>=:NEWVALUE <where>;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a cross posting on Embarcadero's support and they confirmed it as a bug and, like you, recommended working around it by writing a stored procedure. I am going to mark yours as the answer. In my particular environment, I have a reliable way of detecting SQL injection (by something similar to parsing the original SQL statement, parsing it after string replacement and if it is no longer, there has been no SQL injection), so I think I am heading toward doing string replacements until the bug gets fixed. Long term maintenance will be easier without 100's of these stored procedures.

Comment: "Long term maintenance will be easier without 100's of these stored procedures."
Agree.
I am not an Interbase user but a Firebird one. Not sure that your query should work, never test such case.

Comment: I have been doing SQL for 30+ years (many of those years full time just doing SQL), written queries up to 65K character long, so I've seen/used about everything possible in SQL.  I know this SQL works because if I substitute hard coded numbers for parameters, it runs.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-server we would side step this by using variables:

```
declare @i int
select @i = :CUST_NO
select * from sales where CUST_NO  = @i
```

Comment: Question was for Interbase, why do you propose a SQL server solution ?

Comment: And, in Interbase, I could do something very similar normally.  My query was written to find and point out a bug in Interbase - it is valid syntax, but it fails.  The bug is that Interbase can't use parameters in subqueries (until they get this bug fixed).